# Flink on GCP No FileSystem for scheme: gs

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-platform, apache-flink, google-kubernetes-engine

I've been trying to use Flink on GCP (https://github.com/spotify/flink-on-k8s-operator) but there is a problem with google cloud storage access.

So, I've just followed the steps that explained here (https://github.com/spotify/flink-on-k8s-operator/blob/master/images/flink/README.md)

So, I've created a docker image like;

```
ARG GCS_CONNECTOR_VERSION=latest-hadoop2
ARG FLINK_HADOOP_VERSION=2.8.3-10.0

ARG GCS_CONNECTOR_NAME=gcs-connector-${GCS_CONNECTOR_VERSION}.jar
ARG GCS_CONNECTOR_URI=https://storage.googleapis.com/hadoop-lib/gcs/${GCS_CONNECTOR_NAME}
ARG FLINK_HADOOP_JAR_NAME=flink-shaded-hadoop-2-uber-${FLINK_HADOOP_VERSION}.jar
ARG FLINK_HADOOP_JAR_URI=https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/flink/flink-shaded-hadoop-2-uber/${FLINK_HADOOP_VERSION}/${FLINK_HADOOP_JAR_NAME}

RUN echo "Downloading ${GCS_CONNECTOR_URI}" && \
  wget -q -O /opt/flink/lib/${GCS_CONNECTOR_NAME} ${GCS_CONNECTOR_URI}
RUN echo "Downloading ${FLINK_HADOOP_JAR_URI}" && \
  wget -q -O /opt/flink/lib/${FLINK_HADOOP_JAR_NAME} ${FLINK_HADOOP_JAR_URI}
```

I can see the jars on task manager and job manager's lib folder after deploying job, but task manager throws error like;

```
org.apache.flink.core.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemSchemeException: Could not find a file system implementation for scheme 'gs'. The scheme is not directly supported by Flink and no Hadoop file system to support this scheme could be loaded. For a full list of supported file systems, please see https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/filesystems/.
```

The interesting thing here is that the task manager throws an error but I can see the base path that should be created for the checkpoint on GCS successfully. For example;

I gave gs://bucket/flink/job/checkpoint config for checkpoint, i can see this folder after deploying but of course there is no data inside.

What can the problem be?

Answer (score 3):

You should check the official [GCS connector](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/deployment/filesystems/gcs/) docs. Basically you need to copy the optional gcs plugin under the plugins directory to make it available to Flink in your container image.

In adittion to this I recommend you check out the recently added [Flink Kubernetes Operator project](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-kubernetes-operator-docs-release-1.1/) which should provide you some benefits over your current setup and improve integration with newer Flink versions.

Comment: I've checked the official docs and found out that I'm supposed to move `flink-gs-fs-hadoop` jar under the plugins directory, but there is no jars like `flink-gs-fs-hadoop` under opt directory, but there are jars for s3, azure, oss etc. Working wit flink 1.11

Comment: in 1.11 there was no `gs` specific library. You may be able to use the S3 compatibility layer, but I have never tried it. See: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/interoperability and https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/ops/filesystems/s3.html#configure-non-s3-endpoint

Comment: Thank you much. But I can't understand why the solution that I've been trying does not works. I found lots of solutions which work exactly like my solution, so I'm just confused a little bit